# WebRTC on iOS: how to establish multipeer connection (one-to-many video broadcasting)?

Tags: ios, webrtc, one-to-many

Is it true that WebRTC supports only one-to-one p2p connection? Do I have to build my own media server to establish one-to-many video broadcasting? Now I'm using `libjingle_peerconnection` installed with cocoapods in my app and already have working one-to-one connection.

Answer (score 0):

No. WebRTC is a many-to-many p2p connection.

Check [appear.in](https://appear.in/) for example. Open 4, 5 or more tabs and enter to the same room. You will see that it works as you expected. And in their [blog](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Getting-started-with-WebRTC-on-iOS/) they say that they are using `libjingle_peerconnection` for iOS and Android, so it works.

Note: I followed their tutorial and it works perfectly.

EDIT: Yes, you will need a server for the signalling process in order to discover other peers.

Comment: Thanks, but you couldn't follow their tutorial and make it work because I wrote to the author and he agreed with me that there is some logical mistakes in the tutorial which he will fix in the nearest future. Launching appear.in app can't be the proof of possibility to establish multipeer using only WebRTC without third party services :-) and I'm asking about Media server, not signaling, which I already have.

Comment: @SashaKid The code they have in their tutorial is what I have in mine (in Swift) and that works. There is more involved but that doesn't mean that their work is wrong. Maybe I should've clarified that. Right now I'm using [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) for the server and it manages almost everything, but before that i only had a server to store sessions and socket.io to pass messages.

Comment: @SamuelMéndez can you please provide the iOS demo application that you might have to build as their link appears to be invalid.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale Sorry but I cannot help you anymore with this question. I'm no longer working on it